# How to extract ADS marker information to matlab?

Tags: matlab, ads

I am new to ADS software and I want to extract marker values to MATLAB.
Is there any efficient way to do that? For example,
[image]

Comment: Is there a way this data is formatted? Is it text does it come in a graphical format such as this, your question is extremely unclear. And learn how to capitalize and punctuate, its professional.

Comment: Sorry, i 'll be careful next time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use list instead of graph and copy-paste the list data in MATLAB and then select anything that you want inside MATLAB and plot the data in MATLAB

OR

Export the data display plot or list to a tab-delimited ASCII file:

1. Select one or more plots or lists.
2. Choose File > Export > Write selected item to tab-delimited ASCII. The Write Data To ASCII File window appears.
3. Enter a filename then click OK. A file suffix of .txt is automatically appended to the selected file name.

You can then read and plot the data in MATLAB and use Matlab markers.

See this [link](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/ads2008/pdf/data.pdf) for more.

Comment: My next question: I have to sweep the frequency from 1G to 7G(7MHz step) and the response will change at each step.
Is there any automated functionality to get an sparameter file at each step?